# Azure DevOps: How to copy VS Profile settings into a yml script

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-functions

I'm setting up a pipeline on Azure DevOps. Previously, I used to build and publish in VS.

[image]

I created a `yml` file using the Azure Functions template and added lines to deploy to a slot. It looks like the `release` configuration is also set up. How would I be able to declare my target framework, deployment mode, and target runtime in the `yml`? I also need to enable `ReadyToRun` and removing additional files at destination.

Comment: Not get your latest information, are the answers below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the field Arguments to configure the VS profile setting in the yaml build.
Sample:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build project'
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Release  --framework <framework> --runtime <runtime> '
```

Enable ReadyToRun.

Add task .NET Core->change the command to publish and add the Arguments `--PublishReadyToRun true`

Removing additional files at destination.

When using the Azure App Service Deploy task, and you are using the Publish using Web Deploy option, there is an additional option to Remove Additional Files at Destination.

Steps:

Additional Deployment Options->enable select deployment method->enable the option Remove additional files at destination.
[image]

**Update1**

[image]

Comment: Do I need to add `--framework` and `--runtime` if I have these in the .csproj file under the `<PropertyGroup>` tag?

Comment: I also have `<PublishReadyToRun>` in the project file. If these are defined there, do I need to update my `yml` file?

Comment: Also, I'm using `AzureFunctionApp@1` task. There is no "remove additional files at destination".

Comment: 1. If you configure these in the .csproj file, we do not need add these again
2. Do not need, when build the .csproj file, it will be checked. In addition, we recommend that you can use vsbuild task to build your project.
3. I have update the screenshot in the answer, please check it again,

Comment: Thanks. Can you show 3 in yaml? I don't have task based builds. Also, I'm deploying Azure Functions.